# Particle system and controlling the collision on surface on/off dependent on the emitting geometry?

Tags: collision

I have three geometries, two point geometries emit particles in a line, like a laser beam, and the third is a plane.

I could set the third, the mirror, to collide with the two particle streams. Now, I want to have that one of the two particles emitted from one of the two surfaces does not collide while the other particle stream does collide.

Can I set the collision on the mirror dependent on the particle emitter?

I have attached my attempt, which is difficult to see. What you see there are a blue beam a green beam and a red beam colinear on a semi transparent mirror. Here, I want to make the mirror reflecting only the red particle stream and passing though the both others.

[image]

NoLimits

Answer (score 3):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Overview:

You can use **Collision Groups** to choose which **Emitter** will collide with which surface.

In this example I've created 3 [**Groups**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/groups.html).

1. Blue Emitter with blue Collision plane.
2. Red Emitter with red Collision plane.
3. Green Emitter with green Collision plane.

[image: first]

Last thing to do is to choose in respective **Emitter** under **Particles tab** > **Physics section** desired **Group**.

[image: settings]